# Check for form errors on View

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is there a convenient way to check if there are any errors on a form on the view without having to modify the controller or looping across all the elements of my form.

I can do something like:

```
isset($this->formElementErrors($registrationForm->get('firstName')))
```

This is not quite elegant and again, i will need to call that for every element on my form. So is there any way to know if there is any error on the form compilation?

Comment: You can test if the form has any messages using `getMessages()`, if it's not been validated yet it'll be empty, otherwise, if it's invalid, it'll contain an array of error messages, so a simple `$formHasErrors = (bool) $registrationForm->getMessages();` should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$form->getMessages()` or `$form->getInputFilter()->getMessages()`